# Call doAnswer with function as argument in scala play 2.4

Tags: scala, mockito, specs2, playframework-2.4

I want to mock a method taking a callback in argument let's say:

```
methodToMock[T](callback: (String, String) => T)
```

With **play 2.3**, (specs2 version 2.3.8) I managed to do it with the method `doAnswer` from mockito:

```
doAnswer({ invocation =>
  val method = invocation.asInstanceOf[(String, String) => Any] // L.34
  method(role, key)
}).when(myMock).methodToMock[Any](any)
```

But since **play 2.4** (using special dependency *specs2*, version 2.4.2), the previous code won't work, telling me:

```
[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to scala.Function2 (MySpec.scala:34)
```

I don't really understand why mockito start using Java objects in my code, since I'm using the [specs2 implementation](https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/blob/master/mock/src/main/scala/org/specs2/mock/mockito/MockitoStubs.scala) and didn't find any documentation about modifications on `doAnswer`, nor usage example of my use case.

Do you have any idea of what I did wrong and a way to solve this?

*EDIT*:

I wanted to show a simplified case, but that deleted the source of the problem... The real definition of the method also takes an implicit arguments list:

```
methodToMock[T](callback: (String, String) => T)(implicit value: String)
```

Which means that *specs2* seems to return an array instead of a single element (its behaviour really changed between the two versions though).

The following code now works

```
doAnswer({ invocation =>
  val firstArgList = invocation.asInstanceOf[Array[Object]](0)
  val method = firstArgList.asInstanceOf[(String, String) => Any] // L.34
  method(role, key)
}).when(myMock).methodToMock[Any](any)(any)
```

Comment: `[Ljava.lang.Object;` means that you are accessing an Array of values instead of the first argument.

Comment: You're right! I was focusing on the cast and didn't take into acocunt I have an implicit arguments list following the first one, I will update my question regarding that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of specs2 are you using? With `3.6.5` (the latest) the following works fine

```
case class T() {
  def methodToMock[A](callback: (String, String) => A) = 1
}

val m = mock[T]

doAnswer({ invocation =>
  val method = invocation.asInstanceOf[(String, String) => Any] // L.34
  method("role", "key")
}).when(m).methodToMock[Any](any)

m.methodToMock((s: Any, s2: Any) => s.toString.size + s2.toString.size) === 7
```